# Install from USB failed to write HDD

Tags: boot, usb, hard-drive

I am trying to install Ubuntu LTS version on an old HP Probook. I downloaded the ISO file from the Ubuntu.com website. Then used Rufus to create a bootable USB and ran the install. All seemed to be fine until the install ended. Restart was required, but the laptop then displayed  a message that there was no operating system on the hard disk.
This happens every time.
Running "try ubuntu" from the ISO works fine, so it seems the install is failing to write the OS to the hard disk.
Help please!

It's an HP Probook 6470b. LTS 22.04.
I used UEFI boot order (no alternative!).

Installing Linuxfx (based on Ubuntu LTS 22.04) the same way works fine!

Comment: UEFI or BIOS install? Is system set to boot in that mode? How you select USB flash drive installer in UEFI boot menu UEFI or BIOS is how it installs. But then you have to have that as default boot mode in UEFI settings. HP only lets you change boot order in UEFI settings, every other vendor works with efibootmgr which grub also uses to set Ubuntu as first or default boot. Run report only from this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Please answer comment questions by editing the information into your original posting.  Which LTS are you installing, Ubuntu 22.04? What model HP Probook -- some even predate uefi/secure boot.  How did you boot the install media (legacy or UEFI)?  Does the installer offer the choice to "Boot the first disk" (try that)? Does HP offer any BIOS updates for you machine (those sometimes help)?